# Radial heatmaps in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having quite a lot of trouble to create a radial heatmap. Currently, I am using the following script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

losses = np.random.rand(360)
rad = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 360)
r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, losses)
z = 1*losses

plt.subplot(projection="polar")
plt.pcolormesh(th, r, z)
plt.plot(losses, r, color='k', ls='none') 
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I keep getting an error with that script which I don't quite understand the reason why:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

My goal is to achieve something that looks like this:

[image]

[image]

So, each value in `losses` (from 0 to 1) represents a 1 degree interval being a line of the the same magnitude in each point (that's why I am setting `z = 1*losses`) from the center to the surface of the circle. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references to 3D are a bit confusing. Also, `losses` is a 1D array, and for a `pcolormesh` 2D information is needed.

The below code creates a dummy 2D mesh by tiling the 1D `losses`. Also `rad` as name can be confusing. Usually in a polar plot there is an `r` in the radial direction (outward from the center) and a `theta` for the angles around the circle. So, in this example `rad` identifies with `theta`. I created a separate `y` for the radial direction, as it is similar to a y-axis in a regular plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

losses = np.random.rand(360)
rad = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 360)
y = np.linspace(losses.min(), losses.max(), 50)
theta, r = np.meshgrid(rad, y)
z = np.tile(losses, (len(y), 1))

plt.subplot(projection="polar")
plt.pcolormesh(theta, r, z)
plt.grid()
# plt.yticks([]) # to remove the ticks and tick labels in the radial direction
plt.show()
```

At the left the output of the code. At the right the output when `losses` would be a more function (`np.sin(rad*5)`) and with another colormap (`cmap='inferno'`).

[image: example plot]